# Challenges detecting intercom buzz (Particle Photon)

Tags: arduino

I'm using a Particle Photon to detect my intercom buzzing so I can send myself notifications (so far, through text message and Hue bulb activation).

I have a five-wire intercom (diagram can be seen on page 2 in this PDF: http://www.leedan.com/IN-487.pdf) and have tried connecting either wire X (tone in) and wire 1 (audio common) using two 3200ohm resistors plus a diode in series with one of the Photon digital GPIO pins.

I'm attached an interrupt to the GPIO pin, so that I get notification when the pin goes from low to high.

Problem is I keep getting ghost notifications which I strongly suspect are from intercoms in other apartments being buzzed. I get these ghost notifications regardless of whether I have the Photon GPIO connected to wire X or wire 1.

(Apologies in advance, I don't have enough reputation to post images.)

Intercom source --> 3200ohm resistor --> 3200 ohm resistor --> diode --> GPIO

I found documentation for a strobe light that Lee-Dan manufactures for use with their intercoms. (http://leedan.com/IN-544.pdf) It seems they use wire X -- tone in -- to activate their strobe. The documentation says it's 24V pulsed at 1kHz to ground. My multimeter detects 24V as well. But I'm not sure how they only activate the strobe when that specific intercom is being buzzed.

Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

1. 24V is **huge** compared to the 3.3V supply voltage of your photon. You really need to be dividing this voltage by 7 to get an appropriate input signal (which means that 'signal noise' that's ~8dB below the 24V signal could still show 'full-scale' to your photon)
2. It's generally best to use a capacitor to 'smooth' the DC output from a diode-rectified pulsed-DC (labeled AC in my diagram) signal.

Without reading through all of your datasheets for 'perfect' specs, I think something like this circuit should work for you:
[image]

- If the 24V signal is 24Vrms AC, then your actual (peak-to-peak) rectified voltage would be 24 x sqrt(2), or ~34V. In which case, change the resistances to a 9:1 ratio, rather than the 6:1 in my schematic.

Comment: Thank you! But after testing the circuit you suggest I still get ghost events. The Photon GPIO still goes from low to high at random times when there's no buzz.

Comment: @user3279570 you might want to try adding a 20K potentiometer in series with the 6K diode; then adjust it to a little bit higher resistance any time you get a ghost event...hopefully you can get it tuned to a point where you stop the ghosts, but still get it to trigger whenever a real intercom buzz comes through.